# Sending an object via socket when receiver doesn't have it's class

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I have a server which receives some object from a client and sends back that object to client later.
the problem is that the server doesn't necessarily have the class of that object so serializing that object in client and sending it to server and reading it with ObjectInputStream will throw ClassNotFoundException.

I thought about reading the serialized object as string with DataInputStream and store the resulting string in server but it did't seem like the right approach.

here's the code which serialize and send object via socket in client(session.dos is the socket DataOutputStream)

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Connector.session.dos);
oos.writeObject(Connector.session.game);
```

what can I do to read the unknown object in server?
or is serializing the wrong approach altogether? then what should i do?

Comment: If you don't have the class on the server side, how do you know what you will find in the object, which fields it has, what types they are, and what to do with them?

Comment: I don't need it in server for anything except for storage. client asks for it later and server sends it back.

Comment: In that case you can serialize it into a byte array, and just send the server size and bytes. But I'd recommend you use a proper REST server, not a custom implementation that requires you to think of a proper protocol.This is classic for a PUT (for storage), GET (for retrieval).

Comment: byte array and it's size and then i can read it with a simple dataInputStream? that seems like a good idea.

Comment: BTW, i'm not coding anything big, just a simple multiplayer game which is given as a homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for a different and exciting approach, you could do worse than use Apache Avro (there's bound to be a Java variant of it). The reason why is that the wire format in Avro has the original IDL schema (which is actually JSON in Avro's case) in it. This means that the recipient doesn't necessarily need to have ever had sight of the schema to receive serialised data and interpret data. So you could receive Avro serialised classes as a byte array, store them and ignore the content, but just in case you ever changed your mind the data can be interpretted.

If that is of interest, there's a getting started page [here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedjava.html).